# How can I turn this function to tail recursive

Tags: ocaml, tail-recursion

```ml
let rec hf0 k n =
  if n <= k then n
  else
    let rec loop i =
      if i > k then 0 
      else hf0 k (n - i) + loop (i + 1)
    in
    loop 1
```

I have no idea how to do it since there is a sum of recursive functions there.

(Thanks @Jeffrey Scofield for the code)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not OCaml or even fully comprehensible. But my guess is that you're looking for this function:

```
let rec hf0 k n =
    if n <= k then n
    else
        let rec loop i =
            if i > k then 0 else hf0 k (n - i) + loop (i + 1)
        in
        loop 1
```

Here's a tail recursive version:

```
let hf k n =
    let prev = Array.make k 0 in
    let rec ihf m =
        let res =
            if m <= k then m else Array.fold_left (+) 0 prev
        in
        if m >= n then
            res
        else
            begin
            Array.blit prev 0 prev 1 (k - 1);
            prev.(0) <- res;
            ihf (m + 1)
            end
    in
    if n <= k then n
    else if k <= 1 then k
    else ihf 0
```

For simplicity this code assumes k >= 0.

As @kne says, it works by moving intermediate computations from the stack to the heap. In particular, it tracks previous values in the array `prev`.

**Update**

This function is fairly easy to convert because it's a simple generalization of a Fibonacci-like calculation.

But in general you can convert any computation to be tail recursive using [continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

Answer (score 0):

Tail recursion is not your biggest problem here. Turning a recursive function into a tail recursive one usually serves to move memory usage of a linear or near-linear recursion from the stack to the heap (and hopefully even decrease memory usage in the process). It is done because the latter is less likely to overflow.

In your case I cannot see stack overflows to be much of a problem, because far earlier (that is for far smaller `n-k`) you will run into extreme running times. The reason is that your recursion is very far from linear: It branches by `k`.

The technique which you will want to apply is dynamic programming. As a side note (depending on implementation) it can also give you constant stack usage.

[EDIT]
In a comment you point out that your question is academical. If you insist on tail recursion, there are several options.

1. A function call can have only one tail. Hence, strictly speaking, tail recursion can apply only to the *last* recursive call, not all recursive calls. That is easy to achieve in this case using an accumulator: Compute the sum of all but one term using non-tail recursion and use tail recursion for the last term, passing the partial sum via the accumulator.
2. With the execution of a recursive function we can associate an invocation tree. In your case, the tree would have height `n-k` and each non-leaf would have `k` children. The flow of control then mimics a depth-first walk through that tree. You can simulate this depth-first walk in a single loop. (The position in the tree, which you will need to keep track of, closely corresponds to what would otherwise be the call stack.) Then, you can implement this loop using tail recursion.

Comment: I think you are right. But actually this is just a study example and I'm learning how to turn a normal recursion to a tail recursion.